# querying 2 entries that are with the same value but with dates within 24 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have this table:

```
> dbo.IceCreamOrders
> - ID (int)
> - CustomerID (int)
> - Flavor (varchar(100))
> - DateOrdered (datetime)
```

I wanted to count customers who ordered Vanilla 2 (or more) consecutive times within 24 months. How do i do this?

Comment: do you mean vanilla-strawberry-vanilla is wrong? Only vanilla-vanilla to be counted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For number of Vanillas in a 24 month period. Not consecutive Vanilla orders.

```
SELECT
   I1.CustomerID 
FROM
   dbo.IceCreamOrders I1
   JOIN
   dbo.IceCreamOrders I2 ON I1.CustomerID = I2.CustomerID AND I1.Flavor = I2.Flavor AND
                        DATEDIFF(month, I1.DateOrdered, I2.DateOrdered) <= 24
WHERE
   I1.Flavor = 'Vanilla'
GROUP BY
   I1.CustomerID
HAVING
   COUNT(*) >= 2
```